# SQL script, STOCK returning same results

Tags: sql, firebird

I need help with a SQL script. I need to show the STOCK quantity of some products on a dataGrid, so there's 2 tables, one is the PRODUCT and the other is STOCK where I save all the movimentation. This is my script:

```
SELECT PRO_LABEL,

(SELECT SUM(STO_QUANTITY) STO_QUANTITY FROM STOCK STO
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT AS PRO ON PRO.PRO_ID = STO.PRO_ID
WHERE PRO.PRO_ID = STO.PRO_ID) STO_QUANTITY

FROM PRODUCT AS PRO
ORDER BY PRO.PRO_ID DESC
```

the problem here is that all the results show me the same STO_QUANTITY. Each product should show it's own stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same alias used on two different table references and I don't think you really need the inner reference.

```
SELECT PRO_LABEL,

(SELECT SUM(STO_QUANTITY) STO_QUANTITY FROM STOCK STO
WHERE PRO.PRO_ID = STO.PRO_ID) STO_QUANTITY

FROM PRODUCT AS PRO
ORDER BY PRO.PRO_ID DESC
```

I think you can simplify like this.

Comment: why not just use join and grouping? `correlated sub-query` usually scales worse

Answer (score 1):

What is relation between `PRO_LABEL` and `PRO_ID` ? Is `PRO_ID` unique per `PRODUCT` table or can repeat?

Frankly your inner query better be made running all at once, not running thousand times for every single ID again and again. Not always, but usually it scales better as the tables grow with data. Reading "query plans" over real data and real "database schemas" (including "indexes") would be in the end deciding. But if you have no guesses yet, then better to start doing join with single data stream rather than making many-many-many one-line re-queries.

So start with something like

```
SELECT SUM(STO_QUANTITY) AS STO_QUANTITY, PRO_ID 
FROM STOCK 
GROUP BY PRO_ID
```

One query having ALL the sums right off.

Then you might wrap it as `derived table` and use it for joining with `product`s.

```
SELECT PRO_LABEL, STO_QUANTITY 
FROM PRODUCT PRO, 
  ( SELECT SUM(STO_QUANTITY) AS STO_QUANTITY, PRO_ID 
    FROM STOCK STO GROUP BY PRO_ID ) AS STO_G
WHERE STO_G.PRO_ID = PRO.PRO_ID
```

This query might also be written using `CTE`s, a bit more verbose and explicit. Whether that makes it easier to read/compose or harder is a matter of taste. In this simple case there is no actualy difference but style.

```
WITH STO_G AS ( SELECT SUM(STO_QUANTITY) AS STO_QUANTITY, PRO_ID FROM STOCK STO GROUP BY PRO_ID ) 
SELECT PRO_LABEL, STO_QUANTITY 
FROM PRODUCT PRO, STO_G
WHERE STO_G.PRO_ID = PRO.PRO_ID
```

Or perhaps like this (assuming uniqueness of `PRO_ID` in `PRODUCTS`):

```
SELECT MIN(PRO_LABEL) as PRO_LABEL, STO.PRO_ID, SUM(STO_QUANTITY) AS STO_QUANTITY
FROM PRODUCT PRO, STOCK STO 
WHERE STO.PRO_ID = PRO.PRO_ID
GROUP BY STO.PRO_ID
```

P.S. i use `inner join` in SQL-89 style, for simplicity. Would you have some products that you need listed in the query but are missed from `STOCK`, you would have to convert it to `outer join`, left or right, as you did in your question.